# GLIBCXX_3.4.17 and GLIBC_2.16 not found on redhat 6.7

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, redhat

I have an account (not superuser) on Redhat 6.7 and it has Python 3.4.3 on it. The computer is offline. I installed TensorFlow 1.12 on it. When I want to import TensorFlow, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/appl/open_tools/python/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.17' not found (required by /home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/appl/open_tools/python/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.17' not found (required by /home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

I realized it might be because of gcc. So, I looked at the gcc versions available:

```
gcc/4.8.1       gcc/4.9.0       gcc/5.2.0       gcc/6.1.0
gcc/4.8.5_rhel6 gcc/4.9.3       gcc/5.3.0       gcc/7.3.0
```

I loaded gcc/4.8.1. Now, I get a different error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/appl/open_tools/python/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by /home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/appl/open_tools/python/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by /home/r.jack/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

How can I resolve this? One solution is that the system admin upgrades the RedHat from 6.7 to 7. But, they don't do that.

Do I have to try an earlier version of TensorFlow? Or, an earlier version of python? (They have python 2, but I prefer not to use Python 2)

**What I tried after I got comments:** I downloaded a new libc (libc6-2.16.90-3.x86_64.rpm) from http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libc.so.6 and then used following commands to set the library directory and preload to the load the new libc from my user's home directory:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path_to_libc_so_6_dir:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}.
export LD_PRELOAD=libc.so.6
```

Then, I ran python, but I got the same error.

Comment: You need a newer *libc* (http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libc.so.6).

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks. But, as I explained above,  I don't have access to root so I cannot install it.

Comment: No, but you can install it in your *${HOME}* dir (or anywhere you have *+w*) using *rpm2cpio* and *cpio* (I haven't use it for years but I think it's `rpm2cpio libc.rpm | cpio -idmv`). Then at run time, add it to at the beginning of *${LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH}* (or if that doesn't work, use *${LD\_PRELOAD}*).

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks. I am a beginner in Linux. Can you please give me more details on how to "at run time, add it to at the beginning of ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}?

Comment: @CristiFati I'd appreciate it if you could explain.

Comment: Did you try it? Doesn't it work? What should I explain? Did you try *Google*ing the 2 env vars?

Comment: @CristiFati I have not tried it since I don't know what "hen at run time, add it to at the beginning of ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} (or if that doesn't work, use ${LD_PRELOAD})" means.  I am a beginner in linux. Can you explain?

Comment: @CristiFati I downloaded and installed libc6-2.16.90-3.x86_64.rpm. I have not done the step you mentioned above.

Comment: You have to few reputation to go into chat. Now, you unpack the *.rpm* (hopefully you got the *64bit* one) in your *cwd*. Search the unpack *dir* for a file *libc.so.6*. Add its dir to the env var: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path_to_libc_so_6_dir:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`. Then run your *Python* command.

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks. It did not work. Since it is in the folder named lib, I used "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}". The same error after I do the steps. Did I do it right?

Comment: Post the dir name where the file is, and also the **exact** *export* command.

Comment: @CristiFati  The dir name is lib and what I exactly posted was export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

Comment: Not ***/lib***, but either ***./lib*** or simply *lib*.

Comment: @CristiFati none of them worked. I also tried LD_PRELOAD=lib:${LD_PRELOAD} but it did not work either.

Comment: The add the full path to the *lib* dir. and clean your variable contents before. Also didn't work is too generic. Anyway you should edit the question and add the steps took during this session.

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks. I realized I cannot change LD_LIBRARY_PATH. When I say  when I say export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}, then say echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it is not change, it is as before

Comment: @furas do u have a solution?